# Pokemon Battle in Python

Tags: python, project

I am not that great with OOP but I am stuck right now. First off, I don't think I set the damage correctly and I am trying to figure out how to output the damage to the user. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#Pokemon Battle
import random
from time import sleep
from array import *

class Pokemon(object):
    def __init__(self, xname, xhealth):
        self.name = xname
        self.health = xhealth

    def damage1(self,Charmander):
        Squirtle.health - self.damage
    def damage2(self,Charmander):
        self.health - Squirtle.damage

print ('What is your name?')
name = input()
print ('Hello '+name+'! You are about to enter a pokemon battle.')
sleep(1)
print ('A wild Charmander appeared!')
sleep(1)
print ('You sent out Squirtle!')
sleep(1)
print ('Do you want to fight(1) or run away(2)?')
choice = input()

damage = random.randint(1,50)
damage = str(damage)

if choice == '1':
    print ('You dealt '
    sleep(1)
    print ('Charmander did ')
if choice == '2':
    print ('You ran away.')
else:
    print ('Not a valid response.')
```

Comment: Isn't OOP a little overkill for this, considering the type of project?

Comment: @cloudcoder2000: It's a homework problem, intended to teach OOP. I think it's a wonderful project for beginners, but of course the fact that it's posted here is slightly troublesome...

Comment: This is a good candidate for code review

Comment: If you really intend on practicing OOP, you'll want to start by making the program more modular. Separate code that can live just fine on its own into different classes or functions as necessary. If done correctly, your game should be able to work with not only Pokemon, but any creature you can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right off the bat, you can use String Formatting to insert variables in strings.

```
#old way
some_string = "the value of 2+2 = %i",4

#new way
some_string = "the value of 2+2 = {}".format(4)
```

For your code, try:

```
if choice == '1':
  print("You dealt {}".format(damage_goes_here))
```

However there's deeper issues with your code. Let me look more and I'll edit.

## Object Oriented Programming

Okay so the first problem you have is that you never actually MAKE anything. When you write `class SomeClassLikePokemonOrWhatever:` what you're doing is making a template of something. It's like making a cast or a mold of an item before you make it -- you want all your Pokemon (or whatever) to be alike, so you make a mold of them and cast them all from the same mold. You can decorate and unique-ify them after that, but we want them all to be the same, basically. So instead, you should have something like this:

```
class Pokemon:
  def __init__(self,name,base_hp):
    self.name = name
    self.base_hp = base_hp
  #the __init__ function gets called when you "instantiate" (e.g. actually MAKE)
  #whatever object the class is describing. In most cases, all it does it set
  #the starting properties of the object based on how you define it (like this)
  #you could also say all pokemon are beautiful, and add something like
    self.description = "Absolutely GORGEOUS darling!"
  #that will be constant for every pokemon you make through this definition.
  #you said you wanted damage to be random between 1-50, so we don't need to add
  #that statistic to the class.
```

That covers the definition of the object, but it still doesn't DO anything. In fact, let's let it do something, shall we? We want it to attack. What's a pokemon that doesn't fight? So let's give it a function (in a class, we call functions "methods.")

```
  def attack(self,target):
  #in this method we'll teach the pokemon how to fight
    damage = random.randint(1,50) #don't forget to import random to do this
    target.hp -= damage
```

Now you need to make some stuff. You defined what a Pokemon is and what it can do, but you haven't made one. Let's make some. Luckily it's easy.

```
my_awesome_pokemon = Pokemon("Charizard",200) #you give the args in the same order __init__ takes them
your_sucky_pokemon = Pokemon("Magikarp",20) #same deal here.
```

That makes two pokemon, one for you and one for them. If you wanted a whole belt full, you could define an array `all_my_pokemon` and fill it with Pokemon objects defined in this way. Just something to think about.

To actually fight, you'd tell your pokemon to attack.

```
my_awesome_pokemon.attack(your_sucky_pokemon)
#just that easy, now display how much damage it did....WAIT STOP WE HAVE A PROBLEM!
```

since you want random damage every time, you can't access it with something like `my_awesome_pokemon.damage`, since it's a local variable it dies when the attack method ends. You can, however, return that value in the method and use that.... Let's change our method.

```
def attack(self,target):
  damage = random.randint(1,50)
  target.hp -= damage
  return damage #now we have some way to access how much damage was done from our main thread
```

Now to display it, we can do

```
damage_done = my_awesome_pokemon.attack(your_sucky_pokemon) #since .attack() returns the damage it deals, this sets damage_done to a sane amount.
print("My pokemon {} dealt {} damage to {}".format(my_awesome_pokemon.name,damage_done,your_sucky_pokemon.name))
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: My goal is have each pokemon attack until 0 health. However, my teacher is making us use OOP which I do not fully understand yet so I'm having trouble trying to use it.

Comment: Oh, also, I want each attack to be randomized from 1-50 damage.

Comment: OOP is just making some objects have similar parents. A `Dog` class and a `Cat` class might both share the 'parent' class `Animal` class.

Comment: Thank you so much! Okay I understand it now. What was puzzling me a lot was the attack part, but you cleared it up. Thanks!

Comment: @Javier If you have any more questions, don't hesitate to ask. Understanding is key, not copying code. Treat every code snippet on here as a example code -- copypasta is verboten.

Comment: @adsmith I actually have a question. What does the return function do? I was never taught that

Comment: When you call a method, you're expecting it to do some stuff with the arguments its given, and give you back something more usable. I may write a function called `decodeThisForTheNSA` that accepts an argument `encoded_secrets`, does a bunch of stuff to it, then hands it back to you unencoded. I would end that function with `return unencoded_secrets`, and when I called it I'd do something like `plaintext_secrets = decodeThisForTheNSA(highly_classified_secrets)`. The function `return`s the value I ask it to, allowing me to use it for assignment.

Comment: a really simple example, I can make a function called `multiply_by_2` defined as follows: `def multiply_by_2(x): return x*2` and I could use it in my program by doing `doubled_number = multiply_by_2(number_i_want_to_double)`

Comment: So in the code above, without return, I would not be able to use the random number I was given correct?

Comment: Correct, because the function would return no value (it would actually return `None`, like all functions do when they have no return values). The method would still grab the random number, and would still reduce the target's health, but as soon as the function ended the random number would be lost and the program wouldn't know how much health the target lost. By having it return that value, you can use the damage elsewhere.

Comment: I added this to the program... 

print('{} has {} health left.'.format(Squirtle.name,Squirtle.health))
print('{} has {} health left.'.format(Charmander.name,Charmander.health))

but I keep getting some random health. For example... 

Squirtle dealt 8 damage to Charmander.
Charmander did 36 damage to Squirtle.
Squirtle has -22 health left.
Charmander has 13 health left.

Comment: How much health did each start with? If Squirtle started with 14 health and Charmander started with 21 health, that's correct ;). If not, I may need to see all your current code. Since this is becoming less of an answer to this problem and more of a code review, maybe we should take this elsewhere. Why don't you email me so we don't further clog the comments. Post your code on [Pastebin](www.pastebin.com) or etc and email me the link (my email is on my user page)

Comment: I don't see your email =\ if you have skype, I am on right now, if not, my profile has my email too

Answer (score 1):

I really think you should brush up on your OOP and then come back to this problem, because this is definitely a decent problem to practice on.

First of all, you set damage, and then set it again randomly:

```
    self.damage = xdamage
    self.damage = random.randint(1,50)
```

And this function is left open, which is going to cause compile issues, besides for the fact that you're missing any actual data!

```
print ('You dealt '
sleep(1)
print ('Charmander did ')
```

You're going to want to call your damage variable and Charmander's damage variable; think about how that is accomplished in OOP.

Comment: I think he left that last part open to show where he wanted help displaying damage to the user. I'm trying to tackle the larger OOP concerns in my answer.

Comment: Ahh yeah, just picked up on that myself. I actually really like the idea of this problem to teach OOP, but it's so hard to decide where the line is drawn between giving the answer away (obviously very detrimental to students learning how to think in OOP) and giving them just enough to help them develop the OOP mindset

Comment: Should I take away damage from OOP and just set it as a variable and then just make it random?

Comment: @Javier: What you really should do is step away from the computer, get out some paper, and think about what needs to interact for this program to work as intended. Think logically about what needs to be encapsulated where, and if you give me that, I'm more than happy to help you convert it into Python syntax -- that's the easy part. In this case, you can relatively easily accomplish your goal with one class: `Pokemon`, but what does that one class have to do? How does your main method interact with that class? Try to encapsulate everything that one Pokemon needs to accomplish within itself.

Comment: @AaronB: What I want my program to accomplish is... 1. Start off by asking the user if they want to battle or not. 2. If they decide to battle, I want the damage to be a random number from 1-50 for each attack while each pokemon has a total of 100 hp. My problem is that I don't understand how to do this with OOP.

Comment: You're correct in that the first thing you're going to do is prompt the user; if yes, we're going to create two `Pokemon` instances: one for Charmander and one for Squirtle. You can define them like so: `charmander = Pokemon("Charmander", 100)`; create the constructor however you like, for the most part. Since the damage changes on each attack, the `Pokemon` class is going to have an `attack` method that returns an integer as well as an `attacked` method that decreases their health counter.

Comment: @Javier, my answer may elucidate these points a bit. The goal with OOP is to make extendable classes that will work with anything you throw at them, not just specifically Pokemon. I didn't account for that much, because I didn't want to throw too much at you at once, but remember that classes can extend other classes (perhaps `class Combatant:` can have some of this stuff, and `class Pokemon(Combatant)` has Pokemon specific stuff

Comment: @AaronB: How would I make the attack method return as an integer? Also I have a new problem. How would I generate a new number with the same variable?

Comment: @Javier: There are two ways to do this. adsmith has a good built-in method, personally I prefer to pass around values and have internal calculation. It's a personal decision for the most part

Comment: @Javier -- if you use AaronB's implementation, you would call `target.attacked()` in your `def attack(self,target):` function. You would have the random damage amount be calculated inside that function as well, and end the function with `return damage`. Check my answer for more details. I didn't use two functions (one for attack() and one for attacked()). In Python we don't really have protected variables so in most cases we can adjust another object's attributes inside a different object.

Comment: @adsmith: It's generally considered bad practice to directly access another object's attributes (it's better to use getter/setter methods so that you have a consistent API even if things change internally). Either way is a valid approach, but I think that you're better off with two more general methods as opposed to one inclusive method!

Comment: @Javier AaronB is right. I tend to ignore that for simpler projects like this, but generally you shouldn't modify other object's attributes from a separate object. It's part of the broader goal of encapsulation that OOP is intended for. It also allows you to handle other cases individually. If you have a Pokemon that uses `energy` instead of `hp` for whatever reason, having `attack()` call the target's `attacked()` function allows you to have custom code set for each object as to what exactly happens when it's attacked.